# Accountability for Attorneys - does it exist?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, liability, damages, attorney-client-privilege

I’ve had a number of initial consultations with various attorneys for estate planning and entity structuring, and almost every one of the opinions I’ve heard is different and often contradictory. If I just choose one on a hunch to proceed with and they turn out to be wrong (e.g. results in higher tax liability than they claim or doesn’t protect my assets as they claim) is it possible to recover “damages” from them (e.g. make a claim on their E&O insurance)? It seems like the engagement agreements I’ve been presented with suggest no guarantees, no warranties. One even says the company isn’t in the business of providing legal services, and if considered to be legal services they retain the right to facilitate use of attorneys to complete the work (even though it also says all members of the company are licensed attorneys, and they have even emailed me with a note stating that communications are under attorney-client privilege). I assume these are ways they avoid any liability if they are wrong, so how can you hold an attorney accountable?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Lawyers are generally subject to a malpractice lawsuit, essentially the same as doctors and other professions. A successful claim generally requires proof that the lawyer's services fell below the standard of care for attorneys, and that it resulted in some injury to you.

Comment: and finding an attorney willing to take on such a case

Comment: Or the attorney going the extra mile and [**telling you that you shall sue them**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFvCwON0GTE)

Comment: There is an important proviso: you can’t sue a lawyer for what the do in court.

Comment: So there’s no way to file a claim on their E&O insurance, without serving them a lawsuit? I guess then that means it’s really expensive to hold an attorney accountable. also, where is “the standard of care for attorneys” defined? If an attorney is not aware of a relevant tax law, for example, that results in increased tax liability on their client, would that be considered to fail the standard of care?

Comment: That's sort of correct. The policy holder is the one who invokes their insurance policy, but you don't necessarily have to actually file a lawsuit; it is possible that the mere threat of a malpractice suit would be sufficient to induce them to negotiate some sort of settlement. The standard of care is defined in the Rules of Professional Conduct and developed through case law. The situation you describe sounds like it may meet the malpractice standard.

Comment: Also, Dale M is incorrect. Lawyers are regularly sued for what they do and don't do in court.

Comment: Yes @rcibizzle, that would be an example. You aren’t supposed to participate in cases / advise on topics you are ill-informed on. For more depth on malpractice, check out Justin.com/injury/legal-malpractice

Comment: Thanks @bdb484 and A.fm for the clarifications. I’m guessing the busted link above is supposed to be Justia.com/injury/legal-malpractice. What about attorneys that advise and/or create entities (e.g. LLCs/trusts) in states that they are not licensed in? or comment on the protections of assets transferred to such entities under laws of my resident state that they aren’t licensed in? Would that be considered malpractice if it turns out they are wrong about such protections and, say, some frivolous lawsuit ended up resulting in seizure of my assets they claimed would be protected?

Comment: It would generally be considered malpractice for a lawyer to advise a client in an area of the law in which he is not competent. It would be unauthorized practice of law to perform legal services outside the state where you are licensed, but I don't know that it would be malpractice.